# State and next state is the same on openai gym atari

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, openai-gym

i am using OpenGym atari to trainning my Pacman agent, this is part of my code

```
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, action_space):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=8, stride=4)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64 * 22 * 16, action_space)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

#checkpoint = torch.load("C:\\Users\\tuyen\\Downloads\\hoang_chat.h5",map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

env = gym.make('ALE/MsPacman-v5',render_mode='human')
n_actions = env.action_space.n
state, info = env.reset()
target = DQN(n_actions)
#target.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
target.eval()
done = False
while not done:
    action = target(torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32).permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0))
    max_action = torch.argmax(action)
    action_index = max_action.item()    
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action_index)
    done = terminated or truncated
    state = observation
env.close()
```

then I realize that state and observation is always the same when I put this line

```
...
print(state == observation)
state = observation
...
```

how should I fixed this ?